# PHP script no longer writing to database

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a PHP script to record clicks on pages and store a count in a table. A click is recorded once per page, per session.

If a page has been visited before the click count is updated.

If a page has had no clicks and therefore doesn't exist already in the table, an entry is made with the count starting at 1.

It was working but now it's broken a little - it's updating clicks for pages that already have entries in the DB but isn't adding entries for new pages.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong and how to fix it?

**The code;**

```
//start a PHP session
//this prevents spamming the click count by refreshing the page
session_start();


//create current page constant
$curPage = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$title =  '0';

//set number of clicks variable to 0
$clicks = 0;

//do not recount if page currently loaded
if($_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {
   //set current page as session variable
   $_SESSION['page'] = $curPage;

   //try to connect to MySQL server
   if(!$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)) {
      echo "Could not connect to MySQL server. Check your login information; the MySQL server may also be offline or temporarily overloaded.";
   }
   //try to select database
   elseif(!mysql_select_db($dbname)) {
      echo "Cannot select database.";
   }
   else {
      //get current click count for page from database;
      //output error message on failure
      if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM click_count WHERE page_url = '$curPage'")) {
         echo "Could not parse click counting query.";
      }
      //if no record for this page found,
      elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
         //try to create new record and set count for new page to 1;
         //output error message if problem encountered
         if(!$rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO click_count (page_url, page_count) VALUES ('$curPage', 1)")) {
            echo "Could not create new click counter for this page.";
         }
         else {
            $clicks = 1;
         }
      }
      else {
         //get number of clicks for page and add 1
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
         $clicks = $row['page_count'] + 1;
         //update click count in database;
         //report error if not updated
         if(!$rs = mysql_query("UPDATE click_count SET page_count = $clicks WHERE page_url = '$curPage'")) {
            echo "Could not save new click count for this page.";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

UPDATE: It appears that the issue could sit with me my htaccess rewrites but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your to code to find out what is wrong. If it is not adding new pages to database, probably the code never meets this condition:

```
elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0)...
```

First thing to do is adding a line inside the code to check whether condition is really met or not, like this:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM click_count WHERE page_url = '$curPage'");
echo "\n<hr>DEBUGGING: rs=$rs";
if(!$rs) {
  echo "Could not parse click counting query.";
}...
```

$rs should be zero when adding new pages. Otherwise, go on debugging in order to learn why it is different from zero.

Comment: Nothing appears to be being displayed for debugging.